# My angular app will not recognize my service (unknown provider)

Tags: angularjs

ok, I have viewed the docs, and have directly taken this code from another project that works. I have no idea why, but i keep getting an unknown provider error. Ive run through all the possible problems that angular points out on their error reference, so if you are just going to link me there don't waste your time.

the error:

```
angular.js:13236 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=waypointsProvider%20%3C-%20waypoints%20%3C-%20WaypointController
at Error (native)
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:6:416
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:43:7
at Object.d [as get] (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:40:270)
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:43:69
at d (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:40:270)
at e (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:41:1)
at Object.instantiate (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:41:364)
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:87:42
at A.link (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular-route.min.js:7:274) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Appalachian App</title>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="atApp">
<h1 class="header">Yo</h1>
<div ng-view></div>
<!-- Modules -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<!-- Controllers -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/WaypointController.js">  </script>
<!-- Services -->
<script type="text/javscript" src="js/services/waypoints.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('atApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/waypoint.html',
            controller: 'WaypointController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```

my controller:

```
app.controller('WaypointController',[
 '$scope','waypoints',
function($scope, waypoints){
 $scope.helloWorld='hello world!';
 $scope.ways = waypoints;
}]);
```

my service:

```
app.factory('waypoints', [function(){
var demo = [
 {
    name:"Milinockett",
    date:"17 August 2015",
    state:"Maine",
    specificLocation:"motel",
    startingPoint:true,
    distanceFromStart:0,
    distanceFromEnd:2189.0,
    img:"https://56.media.tumblr.com/03645603932681733b6ae4b46d6c7abf/tumblr_o43w4sh5Zu1rrw1gjo1_540.jpg",
    companions:"Vallone",
    ​
 },
 {
    name:"Katahdin Stream Campground",
    date:"18 August 2015",
    state:"Maine",
    specificLocation:"Baxter State Park Camp Site 21",
    startingPoint:false,
    distanceFromStart:5.2,
    distanceFromEnd:2183.8,
    img:"http://41.media.tumblr.com/1a0fd39fd0b14f83ce03151299c883f8/tumblr_o43w7109pQ1rrw1gjo1_1280.jpg",
    companions:"Vallone",

 },
 ];
 return demo;
 }]);
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: You need to add `var app = angular.module('atApp');` at the beginning of your controller code.

Comment: sorry but i already made my app declaration in app.js

Comment: If you put a 'console.log' into the factory, when the app init, it apears?

Comment: @Tana nothing happens, same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first. When you want to debug your application, do not use the minified, but the standard version of Angular. That will give you a far more descriptive error, which will guide you to the source of your issue.

Here's a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/JANQwccTsyqPUTSYAZLv?p=preview . Your code (at least the part you included) looks good at first glance, so I hope this will give you an idea where you went wrong.

P.S. Using service vs. a factory will arguably give you a cleaner syntax:

```
function WaypointsService() {
    this.getWaypoints = getWaypoints;

    function getWaypoints() {
        return [way1, way2, ...];
    }
}
app.service('waypointsService', WaypointsService);
```

Answer (score 0):

Place **waypoints.js** file before **WaypointController.js**

Have any error for JSON on the console. Nothing I found buggy in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your factory:

```
app.factory('Waypoints', Waypoints);

function Waypoints(){ 
    var demo = [ {  ... }, {  ...  }, ]; 
    return{
        getDemo: getDemo
   }
    function getDemo(){
        return demo;
    }; 

});
```

So in your controller inject Waypoints and get demo like:

```
$scope.ways = Waypoints.getDemo();
```